# turning a loop into a list python

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, python-requests

Below is my code: I am trying to turn the loop results I get from this code into a list. Any ideas?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for x in soup.find_all(class_='tombstone-container'):
    y = (x.get_text())
    print (y)
```

Comment: `Any ideas?` - Work your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples given and reading the Standard Library documentation during that process.  This will give you a general knowledge of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem(s) and will probably help you get ideas how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward way to convert the results of a `for` loop into a list is *list comprehension*.

We can convert:

```
for x in soup.find_all(class_='tombstone-container'):
    y = (x.get_text())
    print (y)
```

into:

```
result = [x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')]
```

Basic (list comprehension has a more advanced syntax) has as grammar:

```
[<expr> for <var> in <iterable>]
```

it constructs a list where Python will iterate over the `<iterable>` and assigns values to `<var>` it adds for every `<var> in <iterable>` the outcome of `<expr>` to the list.

Comment: It is also possible to chain more `for..in` s

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to change much of your code, create an empty list before your loop like this

```
myList = []
```

and in your loop append the content like this:

```
myList.append(str(x.get_text())) # EDIT2
```

EDIT1:
The reason I used `myList.append(...)` above instead of `myList[len(myList)]` or something similar, is because you have to use the append method to extend already existing lists with new content.

EDIT2:
Concerning your problem with None pointers in your list:
If your list looks like `[None, None, ...]` when printed after the for loop, you can be sure now that you have still a list of strings, and they contain the word None (like this `['None','None',...]`).
This would mean, that your `x.get_text()` method returned no string, but a None-pointer from the beginning. In other words your error would lie buried somewhere else.

Just in case. A complete example would be:

```
myList = []
for x in soup.find_all(class_='tombstone-container'):
    # do stuff, but make sure the content of x isn't modified
    myList.append(str(x.get_text()))
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over it.

```
map(lambda x: x.get_text(), soup.find_all(class_='tombstone-container'))
```

Comment: If the code runs on Python 3 the result won't be a list.

Comment: @Matthias yeah, sadly.